# Is there a way to add styles to any child classes' :after selector of a specific parent?

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors

These items are children of `.pane-content` `.meta-wrapper` but am really just learning sass and I haven't been able to find out if there is a simpler to accomplish this by adding common style settings to all children of the class `.meta-wrapper` that use the `:after` selector. I've seen and tried example pertaining to targeting child elements like in this [treehouse](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/sass-tip-double-ampersand-selector) tutorial to no avail.

Is there a way to define the common styles that are being used once and then just apply the variable `content: "";` styles to each class?

```
.pane-content {
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 1;
  vertical-align: middle;
  .field-booth:after {
    @include budicon();
    content: '\e8c7';
    font-size: 25px;
    color: $green;
  }
  .field-website:after {
    @include budicon();
    content: '\ea59';
    font-size: 25px;
    color: $green;
  }
  .field-locations:after{
    @include  budicon();
    content: '\e9b8';
    font-size: 25px;
    color: $green;
  }
  .date-range:after{
    @include  budicon();
    content: '\e99d';
    font-size: 25px;
    color: $green;
  }
  p {
    margin: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: I don't think you've spent enough time reading the documentation on the Sass website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `&` effectively tells Sass to pull the entire parent selector inside and prepend the CSS pseudo-class you are about to use. For example:

**main.scss**

```
a {
  color: red;
  &:hover {
    color: blue;
  }
}
```

compiles as **main.css**

```
a {
  color: red;
}
a:hover {
  color: blue;
}
```

So I think that the code you are looking for is something along the lines of:

```
.pane-content {
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 1;
  vertical-align: middle;

 .field-booth,
 .field-website,
 .field-locations,
 .date-range {
   &:after {
     @include budicon();
     font-size: 25px;
     color: $green;
   }
 }
 .field-booth:after {
   content: '\e8c7';
 }
 .field-website:after {
   content: '\ea59';
 }
 .field-locations:after{
   content: '\e9b8';
 }
 .date-range:after{
   content: '\e99d';
 }
 p {
   margin: 0;
 }
}
```

Comment: Precisely the solution I was trying to accomplish, I am grateful to you.

Answer (score 0):

I can simplify your code like that (using placeholder):

```
%childern{
  font-size: 25px;
  color: $green; 
}

.pane-content {
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 1;
  vertical-align: middle;

  .field-booth:after {
    @include budicon();
    @extend %childern;
    content: '\e8c7';    
  }
  .field-website:after {
    @include budicon();
    @extend %childern;
    content: '\ea59';
  }
  .field-locations:after{
    @include  budicon();
    @extend %childern;
    content: '\e9b8';
  }
  .date-range:after{
    @include  budicon();
    @extend %childern;
    content: '\e99d';
  }
  p {
    margin: 0;
  }
}
```